# Cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction when extending auto-generated DAO classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq, spring-boot-jooq

I have been using jOOQ for some time and all is good.
I am using PostgreSQL as a database in spring boot application.
I am using jOOQ Code generation to generate DAOs, POJOs etc..
Also, using `spring-boot-starter-jooq` version `3.2.2` and it uses `jooq` version `3.18.9`

Now I have to extend auto generated DAO like below:

```
@Repository
public class SomeRepositoryImpl extends SomeDao {

    private final DSLContext dslContext;

    public SomeRepositoryImpl(DSLContext dslContext) {
        super(dslContext.configuration());
        this.dslContext = dslContext;
    }

    
    public void save(Example example) {
        insert(example);
    }
}
```

Mentioned above `SomeDao`, `Example example` are auto generated DAO and POJO respectively. `insert()` method from super class or auto generated DAO of jOOQ.

If I call `someRepositoryImpl.save(example)` from service layer, repository save throws error as below:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "public"."example" ("name", "domain", "description", "website", "language_id") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) returning "public"."example"."example_id"]; ERROR: cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse
and so on....
```

I am not using `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` anywhere in my code.

But, if I use mentioned below code in `SomeRepositoryImpl` then it works:

```
    @Transactional
    public void save(Example example) {
        insert(example);
    }
```

Also, if I use mentioned below code which uses the generated DAO directly in service layer then it works:

```
@Autowired
SomeDao someDao;

someMethod(Example example){
someDao.insert(example);
}
```

- What am I missing and it throws exception?
- Also in spring boot is this the best way to extend Dao and provide configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Access to database outside of any declared `@Transactional` context is read-only by default.

It is done to avoid changes in entities being propagated unintentionally to the Database outside of a transaction.

See [SimpleJpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html) javadoc which will show you that the class itself is annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` which makes all methods "read-only" by-default, except the one annotated with `@Transactional` (like `delete` or `save`)